# How to call an asynchronous method from a view?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, razor, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an async method in a controller that has an id parameter. In my view, I want to have a button that when clicked it passes a `@document.SubmissionId` variable to the function and execute it. How can I achieve that? Here is what I have so far:

#### Controller

```
private async Task<ActionResult> onPostSaveImage(string id){}
```

#### View

```
<input type="button" value="Send Images" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("onPostSaveImage", "ICRDocumentPending")?id=' + @document.SubmissionId" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough just sign a method with `async` to be able work asynchronously when called from a view. It is necessary to derive your controller class from `System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController`, which implements `IAsyncController` interface. And code will become like below:

```
public class ICRDocumentPendingController : AsyncController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> onPostSaveImage(string id)
    {           
        return await Task<ActionResult>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            /*  some code */
            //...

            return View("ViewName", (object)id); 
         });
     }
     //...
}
```

View code:

```
<input type="button" value="Send Images" 
       class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-primary"
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("onPostSaveImage", "ICRDocumentPending", new { id = document.SubmissionId }))'" />
```